# What do you call a person who has a relationship with a much younger adult?

Tags: single-word-requests, slang, idiom-requests, interpersonal-relations

What do I call someone who marries or has a sexual relationship with someone much younger than themselves? Their partner is someone who is at least 18 years old.

The term *paedophile* is not the correct word, because it refers to minors.

Comment: If it helps, the relationship itself can be called a "May to December romance."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **cradle-snatcher**
>   *someone who has a romantic or sexual relationship with a much younger partner* <sub><sup>[(thefreedictionary.com)](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+cradle-snatcher)</sup></sub>

You could try forcing a "neologism" such as [juvenophile](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22juvenophile%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), but any term with this general sense is likely to be derogatory and/or humorous.

---

Noting @James's simultaneous post with an unfamiliar (to me) alternative version, I should just add that [both forms apparently coexist in AmE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cradle-robber%2Ccradle-snatcher&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccradle%20-%20robber%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccradle%20-%20snatcher%3B%2Cc0), but [**cradle-robber** is virtually unknown in BrE.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cradle-robber%2Ccradle-snatcher&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccradle%20-%20snatcher%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Interesting --I've never heard cradle-snatcher in AmE, but I've commonly heard cradle-robber.  Maybe it's regional.  Much more common than either (here in America) is the use of the phrase "you're *robbing the cradle*."

Answer (score 5):

An older woman seeking younger men may be called a cougar.

Cougar (slang) - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cougar_(slang)
Wikipedia
Cougar is a slang term that refers to a woman who seeks sexual relations with considerably younger men.

Answer (score 4):

> cradle-robber: (noun)(derogatory) A person who marries or has a sexual relationship with a much younger person.

[Oxford Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/cradle-robber)

Answer (score 0):

If there is a significant financial disparity in favor of an older male, the term is sugar daddy. There are also sugar mommas and sugar babies. There is also a sugardaddy[.]com, as I just discovered, which claims thousands of new members daily. Another sugar daddy dating site promises "Rich Men to Support You.", warning, ominously, that you will "Start living the life you deserve!"