# What's the opposite of “cradle-snatcher”?

Tags: single-word-requests

1. If a *cradle-snatcher* is someone middle-aged or older who has a romantic or sexual relationship with a much younger partner. What do we call the much younger person in that relationship?
2. What do we call a person who is physically and romantically attracted to much older people?

Comment: [Related](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/267995/2085)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to rephrase your question. Otherwise, my answer would be **[gerontophilia](http://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/gerontophilia)** which is probably not what you were looking for.

> - sex attraction toward old persons. (M-W)

[Gerontophile](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/gerontophile):

> - someone who is sexually attracted to old people. (Collins)

Answer (score 6):

I've heard the term "grave robber" being used that way, although I always found it distasteful.

[Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=GraveRobber):

> The opposite of a cougar, a woman over the age of 18 who dates older men. Differentiated from a gold digger because the men the Grave Robber dates are not necessarily rich. Also not considered jail bait, as said woman is over age, however if she was under age she would be considered jail bait.
>
> *"Ick is totally hitting on Jason right now..."*  *"I know she's such a grave robber"*

Comment: OK, I've looked at the first definition. Not *cool*, but there are 7 others.

Comment: @Mari-LouA  Well, hey, it's slang, just like cradle-snatcher.  Besides, I've heard it used.  And come on, the first definition includes "Someone who steals and robs graves."  Hard to beat that level of legitimacy, you know?

Comment: So someone who robs graves is sexually attracted to older people? I think not. Yes, I get it is slang. Yes, I've heard it but used with this meaning: to steal from graves. Good answers require a little work, but the bounty expires in a week and you're likely to earn more upvotes if you "show" the term is also used in the "May December romance" context. EDIT: See? You got an upvote from the community

Comment: @Mari-LouA Heh, I didn't even notice the bounty until you pointed it out :) Just saw the question and thought "hey, that sounds like that term I hate." Honestly, I much prefer "toy boy." Super cute. "Grave robber" seems unnecessarily mean to the older party.  Note: entirely unbiased over here. Haven't robbed any graves.  Yet.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Oh nice, thanks!  My first bounty!

Answer (score 4):

A [toy boy](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/toy-boy):

> - A male lover who is much younger than his partner. (ODO)

UD defines also [toy girl](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=girl%20toy), but it seem to be a less common expression:

> - Like A Boy Toy Except A Girl Instead. Will do anything for the male even though she knows she is just being used for his pleasure. No intimate connection.

Comment: Weird... I always thought the phrase was "boy toy."

Comment: @sumelic [Sinitta would disagree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toy_Boy).

Answer (score 1):

A gold digger is "a woman who seeks gifts and expensive pleasures from men" (The American Heritage Dictionary, 1973).

Comment: The OP is asking for a genderless term. See: "His/her age"

Comment: But gold diggers aren't attracted to age, just to money.

Comment: I would consider "gold digger' to be genderless, And while it doesn't demand that the "target" be older, it's certainly common that that's the case.  (To assure the right connotation is read, one could always use "(g)old digger".)

Comment: @HotLicks "Old digger" just sounds like an old man who digs for a living.  Or an old man who is currently digging, I suppose.  Or someone who's been seen around a lot and for whatever reason is called "Digger."  "Say, you know that guy?"  "Yeah, that's just ol' Digger.  Don't worry about him."  "He single?"  "Yeah."  "He rich?"  "Yeah, but he's like three times your age."  "Ew, never mind."

Answer (score 0):

The (gender specific) term I've heard used is **cub**:

> A cougar's much younger lover. The boy is often called her cub. Cubs are usually sexy young guys that cougars keep around for company whether it be sex or to make her feel young again...cubs are often in relationships with their cougars. Always together. He's more than a boy toy to his cougar he's her cub.
>
> *Check out that fine cougar with her cub! Rawr*
> <sub>[Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Cub)</sub>

Apparently the terminology also extends to lesbians with **lesbian cub**:

> For those of you not up on the dating lingo, lesbian cougars and cubs are the same as their straight counter-parts. Cougars are generally 10 or more years older than their partner. Cubs are the younger partner, and prefer a more mature mate. According to [Lesbian Cougar Dating], “Lesbian cubs are also attracted to lesbian cougar women who are poised, experienced, independent and assertive.”
> <sub>[Pride](https://www.pride.com/lifestyle/2011/09/02/lesbian-cougars-now-have-dating-site-hunt-cubs)</sub>

And also **reverse cougar** is the straight female equivalent of "cub":

> A young woman (aged from 18-22) who is genuinely/solely into older men (30 and on).
>
> *Guy 1: Why don't you try your luck with her?
>
> Guy 2: I hear she's a reverse cougar and I'm in her age group.*
> <sub>[Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Reverse%20Cougar)</sub>

However, this terminology does not extend to gay men ("cub" means something else when referring to gay men; see again [UD](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Cub)). Try **chicken** instead for that:

> a young homosexual male seeking older men; see also: Chicken hawk, referring to an older gay male looking for younger partners.
> <sub>[Thought Catalog](https://thoughtcatalog.com/nico-lang/2013/09/51-gay-slang-phrases-youve-never-heard-before/)</sub>